# How to create an organizational chart from SQL database with flask?

Tags: python, sql-server, database, hierarchy, organizational-chart

I have a SQL database like this:

[image]

Basically this is a hierarchical database where you have managers (parent) and employees (children).

Currently I am working with flask which allows me to add/remove managers and employees and my idea is to have an html file which automatically reads from my SQL database and creates a tree like strucure (or an organizational chart) like this:

[image]

I have figured out a way to create nested unordered lists which can be then turned into the chart by using the following library: https://github.com/caprica/jquery-orgchart

However this works basically only when the database is static and does not change over time. I saw some solutions where they use json files but I have no clue of the middle step that leads from the SQL database to the json file.

Therefore, would you be able to propose an approach to solve this problem starting from the database? Which solution do you recommend? Are there any tutorials / examples that I could follow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s thank for the comment. Well to tell the truth I am not sure yet. I am doing a prototype on sqlite3 but i think that eventually i will be using sql-server. Does the answer change a lot based on that?

Comment: Valid point - and yes, it can help to know what you're using / considering. Many things are beyond the SQL standard and become vendor-specific , so knowing what actual database system you're using can help find the optimal solution. If you're not sure on that yet - I'd explicitly mention that in your question so that your readers will also know you're still trying to decide - that can be helpful to know, too

Comment: @marc_s ok according to your suggestion we changed to sql-server

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2016 or later, you can extract data as JSON using T-SQL. An example using your pseudo-table:

`SELECT employee, employee_id, manager_id FROM employee_table FOR JSON PATH`

The output of that query will be a single column with the table data formatted as JSON. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).